# How to add all items if it doesn't match the filter?

Tags: android, listview, listview-filter

I implemented a filter class in my application to filter `ListView`. Now I want to add all items of `expressionlist` in `ListView` when the user type in and doesn't match the filter, instead of display `ListView` in blank.
How can I do this? I need some help.

```
public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        expressionlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            expressionlist.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (Expression wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getWord().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    expressionlist.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you filter by search keyword. You can check the size of result array.
If it is empty, add the data that you want to display then `notifyDataSetChanged`

```
public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        expressionlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }

        if(expressionlist.size() == 0){
           // add all items of expressionlist
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void filterData(String strSearch) {

        strSearch = strSearch.toLowerCase();
        arrList.clear();

        if (strSearch.isEmpty()) {
            arrList.add()//add your main arrmainlist
        } else {

            String usernameArr[] = strSearch.split(" ");

            for (String query : usernameArr) {
                for (upto your arrlist size) {
                    like if (data.getQues().toLowerCase().contains(keyWord.toLowerCase())
                        || data.getAns().toLowerCase().contains(keyWord.toLowerCase())) {
                    if (!tempList.contains(data)) {
                        tempList.add(data);
                    }
                    if (newList.size() > 0) {
                        check your temp list already in your arraylist/hashmap.
```

Then Add to main arraylist/hashmap
                        }
                    }

```
            }

        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
```